# how to implement breadcrumb using angular2's router

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

I use `angular2` recently, but don't know how to implement `breadcrumb` component, any one can help?

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px;">
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a [how to?]>home</a></li>
      <li class="active">detail</li>
   </ol>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be too easy currently.
There is an open issue to support this use-case https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5318

Comment: yep, I read this issues. I think, using a static router config is not a nice way, but a solution

Answer (score 0):

well me too want to use `Breadcrumb` for my project and after searching alot found Nothing about `Breadcrumb` , so have decided
to create my own. so by using bootflat styling (http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html) i have created my own Breadcrumb
for angular2 project. This Breadcrumb also support Routing in angular2. you just have to use these predefined components
given here in the repo.

https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

here is the code for using Breadcrum in HTML file:

```
<breadcrumb>
    <tab name="Home" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></tab>
    <a [routerLink]="['/Components']">
        <tab name="Cutom Angular 2 Components" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></tab>
    </a>
    <tab action="active" name="Datepicker" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></tab>
</breadcrumb>
```

hope this may help you and will useful for others too.

here is Demo for the Breadcrumb.

[image]