# How to get parent route instruction from child component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

Is it possible to get parent route instructions in some child component?

I try to create some breadcrumbs component and I can get route instruction for current component and for his child, but I have no idea how to get parent route instruction (it`s very important, because when I insert some path in URL and move to them, breadcrumbs should get all route tree data for correct self-rendering, not only the current component).

I use this way to get current route instr.  It`s normal or some better way exist?

```
constructor(private _router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._router.subscribe((value) => {
      this._router.recognize(value).then(instruction => {
        let component = instruction.component,
          crumb = component.routeData.get('routeLabel');

        this.crumbsGenerate(crumb);
      });
}
```

Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570624/how-to-implement-breadcrumb-using-angular2s-router ?

Comment: It`s not a duplicate. Because I want to know how to get parent level route instructions.

Comment: Not found correct answer (maybe I ask incorrect question, I don`t know) so I resolved my issue with hard force. Just concatenated and handled data from my current instructions.

Comment: There is currently just no easy answer. There is a bigger rework planned for the router and the API will be improved. But such things take some time.

Comment: Thanks Gunter for your answer=) I will wait :)

Comment: The wait is over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312417/angular2-router-get-route-data-from-url-to-display-breadcrumbs